# Why is the regular expression trying to make submatch?

Tags: c#, regex

I am a newbie with regex so please bear with me if this is a trivial question. I am following [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial/).
I want to see if my input has the following pattern:

```
<any number of spaces><one or more of alphanumeric character>;<any number of possible spaces>
```

If my input has the above expression then I return matches.

The regular expression that I have is as follows:

```
\s*\w+\s*?;\s*
```

When I do

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

even if I have a valid input like `"a;"` or `"   a;"` I end up getting a false.

When I examine using RegEx tool, it seems it matches the whole thing and then it tries to find submatch with second \s* again at which point it says no sub match. Can anyone explain why I am getting a false?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("a;", @"\s*\w+\s*?;\s*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));` returns `true` for me. Though I'd use `^\s*\w+\s*;\s*$` regex.

Comment: I get the same result as @Ulug. Are you sure that `pattern`'s value is `\s*\w+\s*?;\s*`? Maybe it's escaped incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will simply work according to your needs.

```
\s*\w+;\s*
```

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("a;",    @"\s*\w+;\s*"));  // True
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("   a;", @"\s*\w+;\s*"));  // True
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("a;   ", @"\s*\w+;\s*"));  // True
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. Just curious though why would \s*\w+\s*?;\s* do submatching and did not work.

Comment: @ArunavDev the question mark is causing the problem. A question mark following a * makes the match lazy and my guess is that it isn't being compiled correctly.

Comment: @ArunavDev perhaps you had a space in your pattern, it works as well. See [here](http://ideone.com/SudrpX)

Comment: Strange, it does not work for me. I am using .NET 4.5.1 though. Could that be an issue? I thought ?* does lazy search.

Comment: You mean `*?` not `?*`

Comment: Why did the second later answer that was identical to my answer get flagged as correct?  Not that it matters, but it is odd. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the middle term: "\s*?".  You should read a regex in groups, so you have (all spaces are to signify groups and not part of regex): \s* \w+ \s*? ; \s*

What is it going to do with: \s*?

You should have 
    \s*\w+;\s* 
and that should work.

Comment: Thanks tradetree.  \s*\w+;\s* works. \s*\w+\s*?;\s* should have worked too (I guess \w also takes care of whitespace character?) I tried with parenthesis for grouping with \s*\w+\s*?;\s*, it did not work.

Comment: I see other answers that think \s*? should work, but I would never do this as I do not know what the definition would be for "*?".  Instead, the other sensible answer is "\s*\w+\s\*;\s\*"